# I have an audio data stream from ffmpeg, how can I play it in a browser?

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, client-side

I've been able to successfully stream live audio from my mic to my node server.  I would now like to stream that to all connected clients.  I have been trying to do it with web sockets.

I'm streaming the audio with this command

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0 -acodec mp2 -f mp3 -r 30 http://localhost:8086
```

Node gets the buffer array and I write it to all connected clients like so with the 'ws' package

```
// HTTP Server to accept incomming MP3 Stream (audio)
var audioServer = require('http').createServer( function(request, response) {

       audioSocket.broadcast(data, {binary:true});

}).listen(8086);

var audioSocket = new (require('ws').Server)({port: 8088});
audioSocket.broadcast = function(data, opts) {

    for( var i in this.clients ) {
        this.clients[i].send(data);
    }
};
```

Any idea of how I can play this data on a browser?  I tried following this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365335/decodeaudiodata-returning-a-null-error?answertab=active#tab-top) but the decodeAudioData() method fails.

My client side code

```
node={};
var audio = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8088/');
audio.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
var context = new webkitAudioContext();

audio.onmessage = function(data){
    node.buf=data.data;
    node.sync=0;
    node.retry=0;
    decode(node);
}

function syncStream(node){ // should be done by api itself. and hopefully will.
    var buf8 = new Uint8Array(node.buf); 
    buf8.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;
    var i=node.sync, b=buf8;
    while(1) {
        node.retry++;
        i=b.indexOf(0xFF,i); if(i==-1 || (b[i+1] & 0xE0 == 0xE0 )) break;
        i++;
    }
    if(i!=-1) {
        var tmp=node.buf.slice(i); //carefull there it returns copy
        delete(node.buf); node.buf=null;
        node.buf=tmp;
        node.sync=i;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function decode(node) {
    context.decodeAudioData(node.buf,
    function(decoded){
        node.source  = context.createBufferSource();
        node.source.connect(context.destination);
        node.source.buffer=decoded; 
        node.source.noteOn(context.currentTime);
        console.log('IT WORKED!  DECODED', decoded);
    },
    function(){ // only on error attempt to sync on frame boundary
        //console.log('error');
        if(syncStream(node)) decode(node);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you doing this for fun or for real life product? we have successfully used vlc streaming server in one of our projects, installing it on Ubuntu was easy http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html

Comment: I'm mostly doing this for a school project.  It has to be streamed to a web browser so vlc won't work

Comment: I see, anyway, vlc run on the server side on this setup and steaming to whatever client you'd want, for example https://wiki.videolan.org/Simple_Stream_VLC_to_Website/

Comment: Problem is that I'd like to stream over WAN, and the machine that is streaming the video wouldn't be able to handle much traffic.  I'd like to stream the video to a web server (node) and then write that data to all the connected clients from there.